# How to correctly state internationalization keys/values in YAML files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, yaml

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to know how to correctly state internationalization keys/values in YAML files (I have a couple of questions/doubts...). That is, I have a locale file containing the following code:

```
en:
  # Note the 'style' HTML property and the ':' at the end
  test_key_html: <span style='color: #4682B4;'>Test text</span>:
```

1. How should I correctly add colon (punctuation) to a YAML file (maybe by using HTML code)?
2. How should I properly state the HTML 'style' property in the YAML file? What do you advise about?

Answer (score 1):

Those translation files aren't meant to have HTML. I would avoid having the entire HTML string in there, instead just have the string "Test text" and move the html portion back into your template or helper.

Comment: And how I should "handle" (that is, what is a common practice to "handle") situations like `Some text before <span style='color: #4682B4;'>Test text</span> some text after`**?** And about colon punctuation?

Comment: If it's all really supposed to belong to one key, then it would be annoying to break it up into 3 parts (but you could do that), try putting the value in double quotes. That should let it ignore the special characters.

Comment: "Generally" speaking, is it a common practice to break a text up into 3 parts for internationalization purposes?

Comment: Relating to colon punctuation, if in the YAML file I use, for example, the `":"` code it outputs exactly the `":"` string (including double quotes).

Comment: I've seen it go both ways depending on the number of supported internationalizations. It's "better" to not embed presentation formatting of any kind, including HTML into the translation, because then if you want to change that presentation, you have to do it for every translation. However, if the WAY it is formatted is somehow important to that particular translation, then it would be proper to include it there.